# what is wrong in making linked list from file

Tags: c, file, file-io, linked-list

I want to make a linked list from this file:

```
asd
aids
iwill
```

This is the function that makes linked list and returns its head:

```
firstNames* insertOfFirstNameF(FILE* file){
    char name[15];
    firstNames* head,*newPtr,*temp;
    while((head=(firstNames*)(malloc(sizeof(firstNames))))==NULL);
    fgets(name,12,file);
    head->name=name;
    head->linkPtr=NULL;
    temp=head;
    while(fgets(name,12,file)){
        while((newPtr=(firstNames*)(malloc(sizeof(firstNames))))==NULL);
        newPtr->name=name;
        newPtr->linkPtr=NULL;
        temp->linkPtr=newPtr;
        temp=newPtr;
    }
    return head;
}
```

struct `firstNames` has two fields that I have used both of them in my code.

This is main function:

```
int main(){
    FILE* file;
    file=fopen("firstnames.txt","r");
    firstNames* head=insertOfFirstNameF(file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

I expexted it returns a head that its name field is "asd" (first of the file) but its name field is "iwill" instead;

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is a local variable and it's contents will no longer exists after the function returns, i would suggets a quick fix

```
head->name=strdup(name);
```

and

```
newPtr->name=strdup(name);
```

you should remember to `free` the `name` member of each node in the list, and **Don't cast** `malloc` **in c**.

Comment: I shouldn't cast malloc?Then I will have an IntelliSense error.